# Embedding report on C# ASP.NET page failing content type error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, report

All I'm trying to do is embed a report on a ASP.NET webpage using the Reportviewer control and add the parameters to it but I am getting the following error

`Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response.`

Here is my code

```
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://devss370:14112/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx");// new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString());
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["Report"].ToString();// +Server.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["reportPath"].ToString());

            #region Get Parameters
            string[] fullParamList = Server.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["reportPath"].ToString()).Split('&');
            List<ReportParameter> reportParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
            foreach (string param in fullParamList)
            {
                if (param.Split('=').Count() == 2)
                {
                    ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter();
                    rp.Name = param.Split('=')[0];
                    rp.Values.Add(param.Split('=')[1]);
                    reportParameters.Add(rp);
                }
            }
            reportViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = 90000;
            reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
            #endregion

            reportViewer.DataBind();
```

And it always fails on the SetParameters line...

This has now wasted 7 hours of my life so if anyone can point out the blatantly obvious it would be awesome :)

Comment: I'd first check the report server for any kind of error logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters.toArray());
```